# How to write React Semantic UI Dropdown inside Input in Redux Form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

When i select unit from drop down it changes the user input value. I want user input value and unit from drop down. How can I Solve this problem. Please Help me..!!!

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { Form, Dropdown, Input } from "semantic-ui-react";
```

This is Custom Input from React Semantic UI for Redux

```
const renderInput = field => (
<Input {...field.input} 
label = { <Dropdown
label={field.label}
onChange={(e, { value }) => field.input.onChange(value)}
options={[
{ key: "g", text: "gram", value: "gram" },
{ key: "kg", text: "kg", value: "Kg" },
{ key: "ml", text: "ml", value: "ml" },
{ key: "l", text: "litre", value: "litre" }
]}
defaultValue = "gram"
placeholder={field.placeholder}
/>}
labelPosition = "right"
onChange={(e, { value }) => field.input.onChange(value)}

/>
);
```

This is My Form Section for Rendering

```
const dropForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, reset } = props;
return (
<Fragment>
 <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
 <Form.Group inline>
          <label>Quantity</label>
          <Field component={renderInput} name="Quantity" 

          />
</Form>
</Fragment>
);
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: "input"
})(dropForm );
```